# How can I access files in NAS through VBA

Tags: vba, server, port, nas

I'm building product inspection system using VBA 
in a manufacturing company which is SMB.

Succeeded to access DB in NAS(it was pre-installled) to
read and write data.

But I can't figure out how to access files in NAS Server
I need to read and show item pictures on userform 
for users to check Item and Part Number

Currently doing it using network connection
(It considers NAS is connected as local & VPN network participant
 so i just load it like "pictures.insert("10.0.0.#######.jpg")")

is there any other way to connect and access the picture
not by VPN

prbly i should write codes to 
connect / find forwarded port / verify as user / read file

but dont know how. 
Thank you for any advice or opinions alot!

Comment: Just map a drive letter (N:) to the NAS folder of your choice
Net Use N: \\10.0.0.10\yourfolder

Comment: that would work when NAS drive is in local network or VPN. But when it is not on network?

Comment: NAS=Network Attached Storage. Without a network it is not NAS

Comment: Sorry wrong expression. I meant 'not on windows local or localized network drive such as VPN'. because users(factory workers) in sites sometimes get confused to log in to VPN. actually what I want to know is how to proceed to 'connect(using DDNS)-login as user-load picture to sheet or userform' in my vba project without any users' extra job